# Does large VARCHAR take up more room in the transaction log

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, transaction-log, datatypes, varchar

On SQL Server, would VARCHAR(500) take up more space in the transaction log than VARCHAR(100) when all the rows have no more than 100 characters?

Comment: I think the answer is "no", but I guess I don't know everything about every DBMS. So which RDBMS is this? oracle? sql-server? It's probably a good idea to add a tag to indicate which it is.

Comment: Would you mind providing an example INSERT/UPDATE statement for the scenario you're thinking of?

Comment: I remember a video...I think it was from Paul Randal or Kim Tripp... where they said that. I think it was for rolling back. I don;t have a specific query. I started a new company and noticed the developers do not seem to care about the size of there VARCHAR since it does not take up the space on the drive.

Comment: Do they care about performance? Larger varchars means more memory needed in execution plans to hold the result for sorting and hash operators - memory that won't be used in the end. I.e., you get memory hogs, essentially "reducing the amount of memory in your machine". Give it a try and you'll see.Create two tables one with varchar(40) and another with, say varchar(5000), include that column in the SELECT list and do a, ORDER BY (over any column you like). Watch the execution plan, properties on the outer-most operator (SELECT) and the memory grant information in there.

Answer (score 2):

In the case of a small insert, there is no difference in size of transaction log generated.

Here's a demo script to prove it (SQL Server 2016):

```
--setup
USE master
GO
CREATE DATABASE LogTest
GO
ALTER DATABASE LogTest
SET RECOVERY SIMPLE
GO
USE LogTest
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.v100 (junk VARCHAR(100) )

CREATE TABLE dbo.v8000 (junk VARCHAR(8000) )
GO

--initial inserts have extra log activity from initializing the table
INSERT dbo.v100
VALUES ('z')

INSERT dbo.v8000
VALUES ('z')

-----------------------------------------------------------------
--ok, let's test this
CHECKPOINT --checkpoint clears log in SIMPLE recovery, which helps limit it to what we want to see
GO

BEGIN TRAN
INSERT dbo.v100
VALUES ('a')
ROLLBACK

SELECT Operation, Context, [Log Record Length], [Log Reserve]
FROM sys.fn_dblog(NULL,NULL)
WHERE Operation NOT LIKE '%CKPT'

CHECKPOINT
GO

BEGIN TRAN
INSERT dbo.v8000
VALUES ('a')
ROLLBACK

SELECT Operation, Context, [Log Record Length], [Log Reserve]
FROM sys.fn_dblog(NULL,NULL)
WHERE Operation NOT LIKE '%CKPT'
```